# invert current flow with 1 relay

Tags: current, relay, inverter

I was looking for a way to make the current flow the otherway around through a DC-Motor while only using 1 Relay. Yet after many sketches I came to the conclusion I could not do this without shorting the circuit.

Is this simply not possible? If so I will just use 2 and its very easy.

Why am I trying this? Keeping the circuit simple by using very few parts. [image]

The relay I am using

Thanks in advance,

Anton

Comment: It simple using a DPDT relay. But I don't think it is a good idea: the current surge can be very very big. I just googled 'double throw relay' and found this: https://www.electroschematics.com/9601/dpdt-switch-relay/

Comment: @oldfart the current surge will be no bigger than the current taken by the motor. However, the voltage spark it might produce could be horrendous hence why snubbers are used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you achieve motor reversal using a DPDT relay or two SPDT relays: -

[image]

[Picture source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/149885/dc-motor-reversing-relays-using-a-micro-switch)

If you do use this technique please place a capacitor snubber across the motor or use back-emf diodes to suppress arcing when switching.

If you rearrange the contacts you will see it is an electromechanical H bridge: -

[image]

[Picture source](http://farhek.com/jd/0lb18941/up-arduino/kc11498/)

Comment: What I am using is a SPDT so I will have to use two of those. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just a minor suggestion to make it bold text the part with the snubbers. It may not be the case here, but I know a person who had an arc through his hand because of the lack of snubbers in the case of (old) industrial motors.

Comment: What happens if you use two SPDT relays and one of them sticks?

Comment: @Dampmaskin A short circuit. The same problem for any mechanical switching solution.

Comment: Very great advice about the snubber!But I'm using a Drill motor, aren't drills designed to withstand such effects?

Comment: The motors are but the relay contacts are not. Use a snubber or make sure the motor has stopped before reversing.

Comment: Thanks for your expertise I have zero experience in this field. I also have no clue how big this snubber should be. I found this hile googling `MKP 223J 0.022UF 2000VDC Snubber capacitor` Should I buy this and connect it across the motor?

Comment: It’s about the right sort of value.

Answer (score 1):

This is a better way to wire 2x SPDT relays to reverse a motor. If both relays are pulled in or dropped out the motor is idle (braked, actually), otherwise the motor is running in one direction or the other, depending on which relay is energized and which is not.

No software issue or sticking can cause the power supply to be shorted. If you don't like the braking (as opposed to turning freely) you can use a real DPDT relay or add another relay to get all 4 modes (off/CW/CCW/off+braked)

The rest of the stuff in Andy's answer is good stuff, follow it about snubbers etc. +1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNlyz7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: @DigitalTrauma so the motor is stopped, as I said. If you swap the contacts on a relay then the mother will run with neither relay actuated, which is not usually a good thing.